# Using WriteLine on Powershell to send a script to a router via Serial

Tags: string, powershell, configure, cisco

I am trying to send a string to a Cisco Router in order to configure it

```
#Opens the port
$port= New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM1,9600,None,8,one
$Hostname = "DuranDuran"
$port.WriteLine(("enable`nconfigure terminal`nHostname {0}`n") -f $Hostname)
$port.Close()
```

This work wonders, it does log into the server. However if I want to add another string

```
$Hostname = "DuranDuran"
$interface = "FastEthernet 0"
$port.WriteLine(("enable`nconfigure terminal`nHostname {0}`ninterface {1}`n") -f $Hostname, $interface)
$port.Close()
```

After doing this I get this error

```
Error formatting a string: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to
zero and less than the size of the argument list.
At C:\Users\jorge.ramirez\Documents\SSHConfigRouter.ps1:10 char:81
+ $port.WriteLine(("enable`nconfigure terminal`nHostname {0}`ninterface {1}`n") -f <<<<  $Hostname,$interface)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (DuranDuran:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatError
```

Is it a problem with `WriteLine`?

Comment: ``$port.WriteLine((("enable`nconfigure terminal`nHostname {0}`ninterface {1}`n") -f $Hostname,$interface))`` or ``$port.WriteLine(("enable`nconfigure terminal`nHostname {0}`ninterface {1}`n") -f ($Hostname,$interface))``.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `WriteLine()` like this:

```
$port.WriteLine("formatstring" -f $a, $b)
```

you're actually trying to call the method with 2 arguments (`"formatstring" -f $a` and `$b`) instead of just one argument (the interpolated string). As [@PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39217045/using-writeline-on-powershell-to-send-a-script-to-a-router-via-serial#comment65772534_39217045) already pointed out there are two ways of fixing the issue:

- Put the arguments to the format operator in parentheses, so PowerShell doesn't see `$b` as a separate argument to `WriteLine()`:

  ```
  $port.WriteLine("formatstring" -f ($a, $b))
  ```
- Put the whole `-f` statement in parentheses (i.e. a subexpression):

  ```
  $port.WriteLine(("formatstring" -f $a, $b))
  ```